# Toggle pages issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

I have a hard issue, let me explain:

I have a few Power BI links and I have to show them on a TV placed in my work area, 
so that is, the links have to switch automatically in the browser, but each one in a different time and stay in a continuous loop, for example:

Link 1: 47s
Link 2: 1min 40s
Link 3: 20 s

the browser have to load that in that order. I got some JavaScript code, but it is a loop that runs all links with a same time.

Do you guys have an idea that could help me?

Best Regards, Luiz Bisco

Comment: Hi, maybe show this "JavaScript code". Maybe someone will be able to spot a error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your links and kick off a function that shows the link, sets a timeout and moves on to the next link. If the link counter runs off the end of the array, go back to the start to loop again. I used 1, 2, and 3 second delays just to show the gist of it, but this shows one way to do it.

```js
let links = [{link: "foo", delay: 2}, {link: "bar", delay: 1}, {link: "baz", delay: 3}];

let counter = 0;

go();

function go() {
  // right here, show the link instead of writing it to the console
  console.log(links[counter].link);
  
  setTimeout( () => {
    counter++;
    if(counter>=links.length) counter = 0;
    go();
  }, links[counter].delay * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help me. but I'm a beginner, can you show how it would be in a html code (with a real web site for example)/